# Configure simultaneous dual band AP with Intel Wireless-AC 9560

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I have [Intel NUC Kit NUC8i7BEH](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126140/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i7beh.html) which has Intel Wireless-AC 9560 integrated wireless. When I run `iw` on Linux I get the following output for the card:

```
max # scan SSIDs: 20
max scan IEs length: 422 bytes
max # sched scan SSIDs: 20
max # match sets: 11
max # scan plans: 2
max scan plan interval: 65535
max scan plan iterations: 254
Retry short limit: 7
Retry long limit: 4
Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
Device supports RSN-IBSS.
Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
Device supports T-DLS.
Supported Ciphers:
    * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
    * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
    * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
    * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
    * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
    * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
    * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
     * P2P-device
Band 1:
    Capabilities: 0x19ef
        RX LDPC
        HT20/HT40
        SM Power Save disabled
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        TX STBC
        RX STBC 1-stream
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
    HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 1.0 Mbps
        * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2467 MHz [12] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2472 MHz [13] (22.0 dBm)
        * 2484 MHz [14] (22.0 dBm)
Band 2:
    Capabilities: 0x19ef
        RX LDPC
        HT20/HT40
        SM Power Save disabled
        RX HT20 SGI
        RX HT40 SGI
        TX STBC
        RX STBC 1-stream
        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
        DSSS/CCK HT40
    Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
    Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
    HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
    HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
    VHT Capabilities (0x039071f6):
        Max MPDU length: 11454
        Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz
        RX LDPC
        short GI (80 MHz)
        short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
        TX STBC
        SU Beamformee
        MU Beamformee
    VHT RX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
    VHT TX MCS set:
        1 streams: MCS 0-9
        2 streams: MCS 0-9
        3 streams: not supported
        4 streams: not supported
        5 streams: not supported
        6 streams: not supported
        7 streams: not supported
        8 streams: not supported
    VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5340 MHz [68] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5360 MHz [72] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5380 MHz [76] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5400 MHz [80] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5420 MHz [84] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5440 MHz [88] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5460 MHz [92] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5480 MHz [96] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5845 MHz [169] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5865 MHz [173] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5885 MHz [177] (22.0 dBm)
        * 5905 MHz [181] (22.0 dBm)
Supported commands:
     * new_interface
     * set_interface
     * new_key
     * start_ap
     * new_station
     * new_mpath
     * set_mesh_config
     * set_bss
     * authenticate
     * associate
     * deauthenticate
     * disassociate
     * join_ibss
     * join_mesh
     * remain_on_channel
     * set_tx_bitrate_mask
     * frame
     * frame_wait_cancel
     * set_wiphy_netns
     * set_channel
     * set_wds_peer
     * tdls_mgmt
     * tdls_oper
     * start_sched_scan
     * probe_client
     * set_noack_map
     * register_beacons
     * start_p2p_device
     * set_mcast_rate
     * connect
     * disconnect
     * channel_switch
     * set_qos_map
     * add_tx_ts
     * set_multicast_to_unicast
Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * managed: 0x40 0xd0
     * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
WoWLAN support:
     * wake up on disconnect
     * wake up on magic packet
     * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
       maximum packet offset 0 bytes
     * can do GTK rekeying
     * wake up on GTK rekey failure
     * wake up on EAP identity request
     * wake up on 4-way handshake
     * wake up on rfkill release
     * wake up on network detection, up to 11 match sets
     * wake up on TCP connection
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
valid interface combinations:
     * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
       total <= 3, #channels <= 2
HT Capability overrides:
     * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
     * maximum A-MSDU length
     * supported channel width
     * short GI for 40 MHz
     * max A-MPDU length exponent
     * min MPDU start spacing
Device supports TX status socket option.
Device supports HT-IBSS.
Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
Device supports low priority scan.
Device supports scan flush.
Device supports per-vif TX power setting
P2P GO supports CT window setting
P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
Driver supports a userspace MPM
Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
Device adds DS IE to probe requests
Device can update TPC Report IE
Device supports static SMPS
Device supports dynamic SMPS
Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
Device supports TDLS channel switching
```

To me it looks like it has two bands, but it is unclear to me if it supports simultaneous dual band or not, and how to configure it as an dual band AP on Linux (I am currently using Ubuntu, but can be any Linux)?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401467/193028), it actually has the same `valid interface combinations` as an example. So yes, you can do simultanious dual band (or different frequencies in the same band), but you can only have a single managed ("client") interface, and the interface using the other band/frequency needs to be of a different type. Which may or may not be sufficient to do what you want to do.

Comment: Oh, so no two APs? I do not need a client interface. But I always thought that client interface at the same time as AP has to be all on the same frequency, it is interesting that this device does not require this.

Comment: I have no idea why the requirements for your hardware are this way - possibly there is state both for the client interface and the AP/P2P-client and P2P-device interface in the hardware that only has a single set of registers each.